# SQL Server 2012: check if is uniqueidentifier and convert to string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, uuid

I am trying to test if a variable is a uniqueidentifier and if it is then convert it to string but it fails:

```
Declare @Item VARCHAR(50)
Declare @OutString varchar(max) ;

--@Outstring is populated from various tables each cell separated by ','
--Getting the @Item from the @Outstring and convert it if its uid
DECLARE @Pos INT
DECLARE @Loop BIT

SELECT @Loop = CASE WHEN LEN(@OutString) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

WHILE (SELECT @Loop) = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @OutString, 1)

    IF @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Item = SUBSTRING(@OutString, 1, @Pos - 1)
        SELECT @OutString = SUBSTRING(@OutString, @Pos + 1, LEN(@OutString) - @Pos)

        IF (TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Item) IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @Item) AS @Item --ERROR LINE incorrect syntax
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: fails in what way? please provide more information. Please post working code (you have three `begins` and one `end`). If an error occurs please isolate the line it occurs on and post that info

Comment: what happen when you try this `select convert(nvarchar(50), @Item ) as @Item ` instead of this `convert(nvarchar(50), @Item ) as @Item`

Comment: You get a syntax error for the convert function. Did you look up the syntax? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Eh? `@Item` is already a string. What do you think this "conversion" is going to achieve?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is an if statement where checks if item contains uniqueidentifier

Comment: Yes, you're checking whether a *string* contains some representation that can be converted to a uniqueidentifer, and then if it does, then you convert that *string* to a *string*. What "conversion" are you expecting will happen here?

Answer (score 0):

it is either

```
select @Item = convert(nvarchar(50), @Item)
```

or

```
select @Item = cast(@Item as nvarchar(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(50), @Item ) as Item
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you have said the action but not what SQL should do with it.

Do you want the string to be returned?

```
 SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @Item) AS Item
```

Appended to @Item? (but this variable is inside your loop?)

```
 SET @Item += CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @Item)
```

Not sure what you want to do once you have converted the string.  Maybe you need another variable to add the string on (like above except not `SET @Item`)